# Anyone know where to find the Ilya Frank method's Esperanto books?

Tags: learning

I'd like to try the Ilya Frank method as part of the process of learning Esperanto. On page 12 of this copy of Usona Esperantisto (https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/45436133/growing-up-with-esperanto-usona-esperantisto-esperanto-usa) there is an article about the method. The article mentions two books that were apparently available on Lernu at some point. However, I am not able to find them on Lernu or anywhere else. The email listed for the author of the article is no longer valid. I was able to contact him a few weeks ago through his blog, but he has not yet gotten back to me, which is why I'm now reaching out to the community at large.

Answer (score 2):

I do realise this is not exactly what you were looking for, but here's one with Russian as the original language:
http://www.franklang.ru/index.php/esperanto/126-teksty-na-esperanto-adaptirovannye-po-metodu-chteniya-ili-franka

On that site are a variety of other books, but I think they're all with Russian as the target language.